# send data from javascript to python server

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, webstorm

i am trying to send data from my website(webstorm) to my server in python.

this is the following code for my server in python:

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print self.data
        self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 80

    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    server.serve_forever()
```

and this is the javascript code:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:80");
socket.onopen = function () {
    alert("fdfd");
    socket.send('Ping bla'); // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
};
```

i am receiving the following error:

***WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response javascript.js:20***

any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: I *think* you need to be using a non-80 port for your connection. Try 8000

Comment: i tried also with random ports.. didn't worked as well

Comment: WebSocket is a special protocol (RFC 6455). You cannot use a simple echo server.

Comment: As above, WebSocket is a 'proper' protocol, not just sending 'raw' data to a socket. Maybe you could look at using an existing python implementation such as https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websockets

Comment: so, how can i send data between javascript to python server? i am confused.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the Python web frameworks (Flask, Django, etc.)? They make creating RESTful APIs super easy.

Comment: nope.. i will read about this